# Java APIs for MarkLogic 5.x

Tags: marklogic

I have installed MarkLogic 5.0-6.1 on my machine. I am curious to know does MarkLogic 5.x support Java APIs, using which we can get the content and metadata of the documents in MarkLogic repository. Because I didn't even get a way to create Rest API instance through MarkLogic Database Settings.

Please let me know your thoughts.

Thanks,
Poonam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marklogic 5 Java API uses XCC interface.  You need to create an XCC endpoint on your marklogic server and attached it to the databases you want to use.  There is no need for the Rest API.

Actually,  if you are using Marklogic Rest API you don't need to use Java API

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will explore on XCC interface and will try to connect to MarkLogic.

Answer (score 1):

The REST Client API and the Java Client API were introduced together in MarkLogic 6.